# I want a source code to learn how to make user groups using Redux in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm looking for a source code or articles or videos that could help me adding a feature and that feature is "Groups", I want to add groups into my app, for example,  user 1 joined to 3 groups and user 2 joined to 2 groups and so on,
So how to do this using redux, Please if anyone has a video or source code or even articles, I would be grateful if anybody helps me. Thanks.

That's the swagger API i will use

```
/api/profile/{profileId}/organizations/{organizationId}/groups/{groupId}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best structure I can think of for what you're asking is the following:

```
{
  resources: {
    organizations: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ABC Towing',
        groups: {
          1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Office',
          },
          2: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Drivers',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    users: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      organizations: [
        {
          id: 1,
          groupIds: [2],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

This is how your store would look if John was a driver for ABC Towing.

This structure is assuming that users can belong to more than one organization, and organizations each have their own set of groups. I can elaborate further on how to set up your reducers and fetch data from the store, but I'll wait to make sure this is what you have in mind.

You should search for authentication and authorization articles. I know you're not specifically asking about those things, but auth articles will likely have examples of how to set up your store for users and groups.